# C# dictionary key split to JSON key value?

Tags: c#, json

In C# I have a dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict=new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("User.Info","Your info");
dict.Add("User.Profile","Profile");
dict.Add("Menu.System.Task","Tasks");
var output=dict???
return Json(output);
```

And I would like to change something like:

```
"User": { "Info": "Your info", "Profile": "Profile" }, "Menu": { "System": { "Task": "Tasks" } } }
```

Split the key by dot,then convert into nested key value pair,
because I'm doing the language resource files for angular2,and is there any way to archieve this?thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a recursive function you can do this, supporting any number of "key levels" (any number of dots)

Function:

```
private static void SetValues(string[] keys, int keyIndex, string value, IDictionary<string, object> parentDic)
{
    var key = keys[keyIndex];

    if (keys.Length > keyIndex + 1)
    {
        object childObj;
        IDictionary<string, object> childDict;
        if (parentDic.TryGetValue(key, out childObj))
        {
            childDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)childObj;
        }
        else
        {
            childDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parentDic[key] = childDict;
        }

        SetValues(keys, keyIndex + 1, value, childDict);

    }
    else
    {
        parentDic[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 dict.Add("User.Info", "Your info");
 dict.Add("User.Profile", "Profile");
 dict.Add("Menu.System.Task", "Tasks");
 dict.Add("Menu.System.Configuration.Number", "1");
 dict.Add("Menu.System.Configuration.Letter", "A");

 var outputDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

 foreach (var kvp in dict)
 {
     var keys = kvp.Key.Split('.');
     SetValues(keys, 0, kvp.Value, outputDic);
  }

  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outputDic);
```

Output:

```
{
  "User": {
    "Info": "Your info",
    "Profile": "Profile"
  },
  "Menu": {
     "System": {
       "Task": "Tasks",
       "Configuration": {
          "Number": "1",
          "Letter": "A"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!but finally I found there would be a problem is each must have same number of level,ex 
dict.Add("User.Profile", "Profile");
dict.Add("User.Profile.Title", "Your profile");
this will occur error,so finally I got remove all the dot and use simple string.

Comment: The structure wouldn't make in the given example? You would want a property user.profile, with a value "profile", but also a property use.profile, which had a dictionary of values such as title and "your profile"?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve by overriding the WriteJson method in JsonConverter.

```
class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            bool result = typeof(Dictionary<string,string>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            return result;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = new JObject();

            foreach (var item in (Dictionary<string,string>)value)
            {
                if (item.Key.Contains("."))
                {
                    if (jo.Property(item.Key.Split('.')[0].ToString()) == null)
                    {
                        jo.Add(item.Key.Split('.')[0],
                               new JObject() { { item.Key.Split('.')[1], item.Value } });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = jo.Property(item.Key.Split('.')[0].ToString()).Value as JObject; ;
                        result.Add(item.Key.Split('.')[1], item.Value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    jo.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }
            jo.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("User.Info", "Your info");
    dict.Add("User.Profile", "Profile");
    dict.Add("Menu.System.Task", "Tasks");

    JsonSerializerSettings obj = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    obj.Converters.Add(new CustomJsonConverter());

    var output1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict,obj);
```

Output:

```
{"User":{"Info":"Your info","Profile":"Profile"},"Menu":{"System":"Tasks"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via using multiple levels:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var user = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        user.Add("Info", "Your info");
        user.Add("Profile", "Profile");

        var menu = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var system = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        system.Add("Task", "Tasks");

        menu.Add("System", system);

        dict.Add("User", user);
        dict.Add("Menu", menu);

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

> {"User":{"Info":"Your
>   info","Profile":"Profile"},"Menu":{"System":{"Task":"Tasks "}}}

p/s: You need to add reference `Newtonsoft.Json` to run this example. Reference link: [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can to see about "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject"

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer.